# Get an element inside a class?

Tags: javascript

How can I get every button inside a class and add an event listener to it?

Something like:

```js
var item = document.getElementsByClassName("holder").getElementsByTagName("button");

Array.from(item).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('a');
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns an iterable list.

Your following call `document.getElementsByClassName("holder")` will return a list of elements, you will have to iterate through that list to access the call to the button.

I added the event param to the listener so that you can track which target button was clicked-on.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.holder button').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('Button: ' + e.target.name);
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <button name="button-1">click me</button>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <button name="button-2">click me</button>
</div>
```

For more info, check out:

- [MDN web docs - document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Sitepoint - Basics of DOM Manipulation in Vanilla JS - Working with NodeLists](https://www.sitepoint.com/dom-manipulation-vanilla-javascript-no-jquery#workingwithnodelists)
- [CSS-Tricks: Loop Over querySelectorAll Matches](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/)

Answer (score 0):

Though you can and you should do it with `querySelectorAll`. Here I'm just posting another way to do it with `getElementsByClassName` and `firstElementChild`

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("holder");
var yourFunction = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', yourFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <button>click me</button>
</div>
<div class="holder">
    <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

**firstElementChild**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild

Comment: doesn't this technically add the events to the div and not the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```js
var item = document.querySelectorAll(".holder button");

Array.from(item).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('a');
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll for documentation.

The reason your original code doesn't work is because getElementsByClassName itself returns a list, and therefore you can't directly call getElementsByTagName on it - you'd have to loop through the result of the first call. But the method above is lot less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

If you get all elements with the `holder` class, it returns a collection and you can't execute `getElementsByTagName` on that. You could however iterate over the holders and map them:

```
 for(const holder of document.getElementsByClassName("holder")) {
   for(const button of holder.getElementsByTagName("button")) {
      button.onclick = /*...*/;
   }
 }
```

Or even simpler if you use some fancy css selectors:

```
 for(const button of document.querySelectorAll(".holder > button"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <div class="holder">
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <button>click me</button>
</div>


var items = document.getElementsByClassName("holder");

 for(const item of document.getElementsByClassName("holder")) {
 item.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('a');
      }, false);
    }
```

Comment: this will only work if there's only one div. In the question there are clearly two (at least)

Comment: he'll just loop on document.getElementsByClassName("holder") :/

Comment: well that's not what you wrote....if that's the answer, then show it. Don't assume that the rest of the solution is obvious to everyone else, especially the person asking. If it was obvious to them, they'd have thought of it already.